# Proper grammar for specifying a button / checkbox in a table

Tags: j

I want to create an event handler for a button / checkbox within a QTableWidget.
Below, I've copy and pasted the table demo source code for reference:

```
NB. =========================================================
fmt1=: 3 : 0
if. 2=3!:0 y do. ' "',y,'"' else. ' ',,8!:2 y end.
)

NB. =========================================================
Tab=: _2 [\ 11 8 6 9 23 6
Sel=: 0 0 1

NB. =========================================================
makedata=: 3 : 0
t=. <&>t,+/t=. Tab,.+/"1 Tab
dat=. ((<&>Sel),<''),.t,.;:'USA Japan Germany All'
;fmt1 each ,dat
)

NB. =========================================================
table=: 3 : 0
wd 'pc table'
wd 'cc pac table 4 5'
wd 'set pac hdr Select Hire Lease Total Origin'
wd 'set pac hdralign 1 1 1 1 0'
wd 'set pac type ',":20{.15$100 0 0 0 0
wd 'set pac align 1 2 2 2 0'
wd 'set pac protect ',":20{.(!.1) 15$0 0 0 1 1
wd 'set pac lab Ford Toyota "Mercedes Benz" Total'
wd 'set pac data *',makedata''
wd 'pmove 100 10 500 200'
wd 'pshow'
)

NB. =========================================================
table_pac_change=: 3 : 0
'row col'=. 0 ". pac_cell
new=. 0 ". pac
if. col=0 do.
  Sel=: new row} Sel
else.
  Tab=: new (<row,col-1)} Tab
  wd 'set pac data *',makedata''
end.
)

NB. =========================================================
table_close=: 3 : 0
wd 'pclose'
showevents_jqtide_ 0
)

NB. =========================================================
showevents_jqtide_ 2
table''
```

I want to be able to add an event handler to the check box under the "Select" column, and in the "Toyota" row. From the documentation online, I understand that the correct way to specify an event handler for a checkbox is "formname_childname_checkbox".

However, the childname for the checkbox is never given; i.e. the checkboxes are generated in mass using:

```
wd 'set pac type 100'
```

I've tried specifying the specific cell with the checkbox using:

```
wd 'set pac block 1 1'
table_pac_checkbox = 3 : 0
NB. code here
)
```

That doesn't seem to do anything though. Is there anything I'm doing wrong with specifying the event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think where you are running into problems is that clicking on a checkbox creates a change event, whereas clicking on a datacell generates a mbldown event. If you put these event handlers in you will see message boxes with the appropriate cell designations pop up.

```
table_pac_change=: 3 : 0
  wdinfo  ":pac_cell
)
table_pac_mbldown=: 3 : 0
  wdinfo  ":pac
)
```

This indicates that your events are being triggered properly. What you choose to do at that time is up to you. The sysevents row of your showevents table is invaluable to see which events are being triggered and subsequently which handlers need to be written.

Hope this helps.